# Prevent users to give 3rd party apps access to their mailboxes using OAuth or basic Authentication

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

My users hand over their O365 credentials to a 3rd part CRM webservice for synchronization of calendar and mails.
The webservice authenticate using either `basic authentication` or `OAuth`.
I want to prevent this, except for one dedicated user.
I though about creating a [Client Access Rule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/client-access-rules/procedures-for-client-access-rules) but I can't figure out which of the `-AnyOfProtocols` to use, the options are:

```
ExchangeActiveSync
ExchangeAdminCenter
ExchangeWebServices
IMAP4
OfflineAddressBook
OutlookAnywhere
OutlookWebApp
POP3
PowerShellWebServices
RemotePowerShell
REST
UniversalOutlook (Mail and Calendar app)
```

If I look in **Azure AD** / **Azure Active Directory** / **Monitoring** > **Sign-ins**, which I found [here](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/disable-basic-authentication-office-365/),  I can see when an app authenticate and it shows the following:
Application: **webCRM.Calendar.Exchange**
Resource: **Office 365 Exchange Online**

Perhaps `ExchangeWebServices`?

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in other ways?

UPDATE:
OAuth only support protocols `ExchangeActiveSync`, `IMAP4`,`POP3` ([LINK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/client-access-rules/client-access-rules#authentication-types-and-protocols-in-client-access-rules)) so `ExchangeWebServices` is not possible.

Tried this rule

```
New-ClientAccessRule -Name "Block 3rd part apps to auth" -Action DenyAccess -UsernameMatchesAnyOfPatterns "*MyID*" -Priority 6 -AnyOfProtocols ExchangeActiveSync, IMAP4 -AnyOfAuthenticationTypes OAuthAuthentication
```

Unfortunately the webservice could still login to mailbox using OAuth with user "MyID".

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to subscribe to the **Azure AD Premium P1** subscription (about 6$ mo)
This will get you access to **Conditional Access** where you can create policies to block/allow apps and you can allow/disallow users/groups.
[image]

Pretty intuitive, although it seems you can also use powershell, `New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy` ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsconditionalaccesspolicy?view=azureadps-2.0)) from modul AzureAD.

When you select which apps to allow/block you get a list of known apps to select from and this CRM 3rd part app was actually on the list to my surprise.
Apparently AD record and remember which apps you users connect too!

In this case it was not really possible to use Client Access rules if your app authenticate using MS Modern Authentication, as this doesn't use any of the protocols you can allow/block. 
And it seems the actual authentication is done from YOUR IP and YOUR browser, not the remote app server!. I assume this create a token which is hand over to the remote app server which saved it so it can be used for future connections/synchronizations.

I created a fictive O365 user which was assigned editor permissions to the calendar folders of the users in the organization which need calendar sync with this CRM system. This is the only O365 user which have access to authenticate with this app. Now the CRM system only have access to the calendar-folders, which is also bad enough, but not as bad as access to the mail-folders, yark!